# How to pass array to directive using expression without causing infinite digest

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am currently working on creating reuseable ui components for other developers.

Here is my goal.

A custom directive `my-directive`

which takes an expression that returns an array `item-source="items | filter: someFilter track by $index"`

Angular/Javascript

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngMaterial'])
.controller('myCtrl',[ '$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.items = [ 'apple', 'banana', 'coconut', 'danish'];
}])
.directive('myDirective',[function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<md-list>'
      +'<md-list-item ng-repeat="item in itemSource">'
      +'<span>{{item}}</span>'
      +'</md-list-item>'
      +'</md-list>',
    scope:{
      itemSource: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){}
  };
}])
```

And the HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" layout"column" layout-fill flex>
  <md-content flex layout="row" layout-padding>
    <div layout="column">      
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Using Directive</label>
        <input ng-model="someFilter"/>
      </md-input-container>
      <my-directive item-source="items | filter: someFilter track by $index">
      </my-directive>   
    </div>      
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Codepen
http://codepen.io/jayray/pen/NGEKpM

I understand that the model is unstable which results in infinite digest.

But I believe that for developers it would make since for them to be able to use a custom directive with the same kinds of expressions that are used in ng-repeat.

And I understand that I could do the whole

```
<my-directive>
  <my-item ng-repeat="item in items | filter: someFilter track by $index"></my-item>
</my-directive>
```

But my problem is I am creating a directive that generates multiple ng-repeats with thresholds for when to display.

For example the `my-directive` template might look like this.

```
<md-list ng-if="itemSource.length < 10">
  <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in itemSource" ng-if="$index < 5 || isShowingMore" ng-click="toggleSelected(item)">
    {{item}}
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list-item ng-click="isShowingMore = !isShowingMore>
    <span ng-if="!isShowingMore">More</span>
    <span ng-if="isShowingMore">Less</span>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>

<div ng-if="itemSource.length >= 10>
  <md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in itemSource | showSelected" ng-click="toggleSelected(item)">{{item}} Selected!</md-list-item>
  </md-list>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Filter Items</label>
    <input ng-model="filterText"/>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in itemSource | hideSelected | filter: filterText" ng-click="toggleSelected(item)">{{item}}</md-list-item>
  </md-list>
</div>
```

In which case the previous example doesn't really work.
I am just curious if its even possible, 4 days of internet searching plus failing to come up with my own solution led me here.

Comment: `track by` is specific to `ng-repeat` and I don't think you can pass it in as part of the expression

Comment: let me edit my question, my main goal is the filter, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little research I found that *watchCollection* on expression actually returns the evaluate of it. Thanks for your question, I learned something new.

Assume that i have an array of objects with the id's 
`$scope.test = [{ id:1 },{ id:2 },{ id:11 }];`

I want to get only those whose starts with one.

So i'll call my new directive:

```
<div my-dir="item in test | filter:{id:1}"></div>
```

And the directive should be like that:

```
app.directive('myDir', function(){
  return {
    compile: function($element, $attr){

      // gets the expression from the attribute
      var expression = $attr.myDir;

      // fetch the filters expression from the full string
      var match = expression.match(/^\s*([\s\S]+?)\s+in\s+([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+as\s+([\s\S]+?))?(?:\s+track\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?\s*$/);

      // set rhs to be 'filter:{ id: 1 }'
      var rhs = match[2];

      return function linker($scope){
        $scope.$watchCollection(rhs, function(collection){
          //  at this point the collection is already filtered by angualar mechanism I guess :)
          $scope.list = collection;
          console.log(collection);
        });
      };
    },
    template: '<div ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.id}}</div>'
  }
});
```

The output to the console will be your filtered expression.
`1, 11`

Live demo with the full code in [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vcI1fjqRFONwlw6Oo7Io?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much, works perfectly. I had discovered the watchCollection towards the end of my search but ran out of energy after 4 days. Couldn't put the pieces together. Interesting to see this could be handled in the compile phase.

Comment: I noticed this only works if my-dir does not create a new scope. var rhs will not evaluate. Currently looking into a work around.

Comment: Just did more testing, works if `scope` is true or false, but not {}. not the worst thing in the world but will require me to shift all the attributes to the compile.